# A List of Strings, Item Request Array issue

Tags: c#, string, list, if-statement

```
List<string> arguments = new List<string>(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().Skip(1).Take(4));
int variant = consoleOptions.HandleInput(arguments);

public int HandleInput(List<string> input)
{
        int variant = 0;

        //for (int i = 0; i < input.Count; i++)
        //{
        //    if (input[i].Contains("-s"))
        //    {
        //         variant = 1; 
        //    }
        //}

        if (input[0].Contains("-s"))
        {
            variant = 1; 

            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input[1]) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input[2]))
            {
                variant = 2;        
            }

            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input[3]))
            {
                variant = 3;
            }
        }
        return variant;
}
```

I'm starting my application from Commandline.
Then I get a List of Strings (max 4).

What I want to do now is:

**if the first String in List is "-s" then variant = 1**

**if the second and third string isn't Empty then variant = 2**

**if the fourth string isn't Empty then variant = 3**

I tried some things (Code above), but the problem is, if I only get the first String (one item),
The Compiler crashes on other place (checking Second string, cause Index not accessible)..

What would be the best method?

Comment: You have to learn `else` statement

Comment: You might want to try a command line parsing lib (http://commandline.codeplex.com/) instead of re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: I really tried to use it, but I didn't find any benefits, its also to complicated for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Take(4)` doesn't guarantee that you'll have 4 elements, it just means you won't have more than 4. So you have to check the list length.

```
if (input.Count >= 1 && input[0].Contains("-s"))
{
    return 1;
}
if (input.Count >= 3)
{ 
    return 2;
}
if (input.Count >= 4)
{
    return 3;
}

return 0; //what do you return if none of the conditions are met?
```

Comment: Lenght was not possible, so I used `.Count`

Comment: @eMi oh you're right. When I first wrote the answer, I thought it was an array for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

you try some thing like this.

```
 if (input[0].Contains("-s"))
        {
            variant = 1; 
        }
 if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input[1]) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input[2]))
            {
                variant = 2;        
            }
 if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input[3]))
            {
                variant = 3;
            }
        return variant;
```

Comment: This doesn't address the real problem that the list won't have the right number of elements.